# Field Extensions and Degree.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I had a question, I was just wondering about something.

So there's a question in my textbook that asks for the degree of this field extension for:$$\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt2 + i, \sqrt3 + i)$$

I can break this into towers of extensions:
So $$[\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt 2 + i, \sqrt 3 + i): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2, i)]* [\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt 2): \mathbb{Q}(i)]*[\mathbb{Q}(i): \mathbb{Q}]$$

So for me, it's clear that $[\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt 2): \mathbb{Q}(i)] = 2$ 
(since $x^2 - 2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ )

and also $[\mathbb{Q}(i): \mathbb{Q}] = 2.$ (since $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$)

My issue here is trying to find $[\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt 2 + i, \sqrt 3 + i): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2, i)]$.

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do, my gut is telling me to check if $x^2 - 3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2, i)$. So if I'm supposed to do that, do I just show that $\sqrt 3 = a + bi + c\sqrt 2 + di\sqrt 2 \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2, i)$?

Any hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your field is the same as $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,i)$

Now write the (real) field $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$  as a simple extension
$\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$ (easily verified). Now $x^2+1$ remains irreducible over this degree four field.

Comment: I'm wondering, I know that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt a + \sqrt b) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt a, \sqrt b)$. But why is $\mathbb{Q}(i, i + \sqrt 2, i + \sqrt 3) = \mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$?

Comment: Just show that starting three generating numbers of one side you can get the three generating numbers of the other side by polynomial operations. (Actually the $\mathbf{Q}$ vector space generated by the two sets of three numbers coincide, and hence the fields generated by them also.

Comment: Ah, that's pretty neat. Alright thank you!